# What is a MalformedURLException , and how do I fix it?

Tags: java, exception

What are Malformed URL Exception (java.net.MalformedURLException) and what causes them?

What methods/tools can be used to determine the cause so that you stop the exception from causing the program to terminate prematurely?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/MalformedURLException.html But this exception may occur in distinct cases. Provide a specific case.

Comment: Show the code that's throwing the exception; it's impossible to give specific advice otherwise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Thrown to indicate that a malformed URL has occurred. Either no legal protocol could be found in a specification string or the string could not be parsed.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/MalformedURLException.html

To deal with it, use try/catch/finally to avoid crashing your program.